# Why is some of the text in yellow?

Tags: stargate-sg1-unleashed

During conversations in Stargate SG1: Unleashed, some of the conversation text is shown in yellow;

[image]

[image]

What is the significance of the yellow text? Is it important? Some of the text in yellow is mundane stuff like pointing out that glasses with heads up displays don't exist yet (the top screenshot) while others include gate addresses and dates (like the bottom screenshot).

Is this stuff that I should be making a note of or just keeping in mind?

Comment: Both examples are about half white, half yellow.  Is it possible that's how text is always displayed?

Comment: nope, there are many instances of text being fully white but none with the text being fully yellow